# Way to copy parts of windowsEventLog to a defined location? (sec,app, sys)

Tags: c#, powershell, event-log

I need to create three seperate evtx files containing all events from the last X days found in each eventLog (security, application, system) and save those files in a defined location. 
I am using c# to implement the functionality. It is also possible to execute a powershell script / bat file. If administration rights are a problem is it possible to do this for application and system only?

From my understanding:

1. It is not possible to create eventLogs in custom locations without changing the registry.
2. It is not possible to create eventLogs in the default location without Administration Rights since for creating a new eventlog file it needs to make sure that the eventlog is not already existing and it is not possible to access the security eventLog to check.
   Exception message:
   "The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security."
3. Creating a evtx file with File.Create Method (String) and writing to it with File.WriteAllText Method (String, String) is also not possible

I also tried doing all of this with a powershell script but I pretty much ran into the same problems. $foo = Get-EventLog System -after (Get-Date).addays(-3) -asbaseobject

Answer (score 1):

Check out this VERY useful cmdlet--which I think should have natively shipped with Windows-- [Export-EventLog](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-EventLog-18a87c2c) by Jeffrey Patton on TechNet.

It gives you a new function you can run called `Export-EventLog`, which even allows you to specify a custom location!  It even runs on remote computers!

```
Export-EventLogs -ComputerName $computerName -Credential (Get-Credential) -LogName Application -Destination 'C:\LogFiles1\Application.evtx'
```

Comment: I downloaded this but can't execute the script due to the fact that it is not digitaly signed. Also right now there is no possibility to query the logs (last x days). Will have to look into it tomorrow more.